# Jquery Select text outside/next to a child

Tags: jquery, select

just getting myself familiar with jquery, please consider me as a noob for now.

I am trying to select text in this follow scenrio:-

```
<div id="blah">
<p> <span>Text1</span> text2</p>
</div>
```

How can I get the value of text2 ?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want the text of entire `p` tag use:

```
var text = $("#blah p").text();
```

Otherwise if you want to exlude the `span` part, then use:

```
var text = $("#blah p").contents(":not(span)").text();
```

Your text will now be stored in the variable named `text`.

Comment: i was looking for how to say "contents(":not(span)")" ... thanks man ! ... this was my first experience using SOF :D thanks buddy